# What latest verison of Play! framework should I use when only JDK 1.7 is allowable?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, java-7

What latest verison of Play! framework should I use when only JDK 1.7 is allowable?

I worry that 1.8 features in the Play!'s source code may affect the compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play 2.3 is the latest version which supports Java 7.